# Where to get a client to connect to ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I was told that I need `VMware vSphere Client`, and that it is hard to find the download link.

In fact it is true. I cannot find it on the VMware web site.

I need a free client to connect to our [ESXi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ESX#VMware_ESXi) machines to manage them. Is there any client for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you know the IP address of the ESXi server? Just pop that IP adress into your web browser (and accept the certificate warning), and you can download the vSphere client directly from the ESXi server itself.

There is no client for OSX however. It is for Windows only.

Comment: Not with v5 which was announced about an hour ago :)

Comment: Damnit, I must get a new crystal ball.

Answer (score 3):

As of yet, there's no vSphere Client for OS X. If you have an iPad, there's actually a client for that, strangely enough.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vmware-vsphere-client-for/id417323354?mt=8

Comment: The iPad app is pretty good, but it's limited in what it can do. Also, you require vSphere to get the most out of it.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, if all you need is basic control from OSX, check out Orbit-VM at https://code.google.com/p/orbit-vm/

> It's aim is to provide an open source, cross-platform GUI for managing vSphere 4 servers.

However, I use this to manange my ESXi 5 box and it works great on Mountain Lion!